# Using cgaffinetransformmakescale and cgaffinetransformmakerotation deforms my view

Tags: objective-c, cgaffinetransform

I have a simple UIView:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self.view addSubview:view];
self.someView = view;
```

Then I do this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10
                      delay:1
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
    self.someView.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds) - CGRectGetWidth(self.someView.frame) / 2, 150);

                     CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
                     self.someView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 2, 0.5);

}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                 }];
```

While is executed this simple animation, `someView` is  deformed. As far as I know it should rotate and change it's size. I can't understand why is it happening so, how can i fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is animating a combined scaling and rotation. The end result is the same as animating them separately, but the frames in between are not easily defined. So the animation framework makes a guess, and it is not what you are expecting.

If you want the animation to show a rotation and scaling separately, you need to apply them separately to the view hierarchy. For example:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self.view addSubview:view];
self.someView = view;

UIView *innerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];
innerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[view addSubview:innerView];
self.someInnerView = innerView;
```

The animation splits the transform:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10
                      delay:1
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.someView.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds) - CGRectGetWidth(self.someView.frame) / 2, 150);

                     self.someView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
                     self.someInnerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 0.5);

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                 }];
```